# POI read with diacritics

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I managed to read from a .xlsx file from java using Apache POI.
Only problem is in my .xlsx I have names and other strings which contain diacritics(î,ț,â,ă,ș).

Now when I try to print cell values from java insteadof diacritics I get ??.

Any suggestions regarding this?

UPDATE:Ok so the data format that I get from the .xlsx file appears to be ok as if I wrote the  data into another .xlsx file and it's ok.

The only problem is when I try to print something to System.Out.println(diacritic_string).

Comment: please don't add fixed to the title. Post your solution as an answer and accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change String to UTF-8 and it is ok.